# Moving 3 pics randomly to another directory

Tags: command-line, files

I am using Linux and I'm in a folder it has 10 .jpg images I want to move 3 pictures only without selection by name or size for example my folder is /sdcard /DCIM/camera/ I want 3 pictures from it to /sdcard using a Linux command it's possible? Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a lot of commands possible to do it.

That's a suggestion:

```
cd /sdcard/DCIM/camera/
i=0
for x in *.jpg; do
  if [ "$i" = 3 ]; then break; fi
  mv "$x" /sdcard
  i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: `*.jpg` will sort the filenames according to locale's collation rules, so this isn't random (but it probably doesn't matter to the OP - noting just in case somebody is looking for something more random)